# Retrieve base64 image stored as a CLOB from derby with Worklight adapter

Tags: image, base64, ibm-mobilefirst, derby, clob

I am trying to retrieve an image stored as a CLOB in a Derby DB via a Worklight SQL adapter.   I would like to do something similar to what was written up here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/jsonstore_revisited_in_worklight_v6_part_1_the_adapter?lang=en
except for the referenced article the author is using DB2.  Does anyone know how I can do this in Derby?  Currently when I go to retrieve the image doing a SQL Select, the string returned is

"IMAGE": "org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedClob@2d236"

I would also consider mysql as an alternative.   Thanks for any suggestions.

JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedClob is a java.sql.Clob, so if you have the CLOB in a var, you should be able to get the data with:

```
var dataAsString = theClob.getSubString(1, theClob.length());  // Assumes all CLOBS are < 2G
```

Comment: David, Thanks for the help.  I've tried using the subString method in both the adapter code and the client-side code.  When I call the getSubString method on the adapter, I see the error:

Comment: David, Thanks for the help.  I've tried using the subString method in both the adapter code and the client-side code.  When I call the getSubString method on the adapter, I see the error:  "you cannot invoke other java.sql.Clob/java.sql.Blob methods after calling the free() method or after the Blob/Clob's transaction has been committed or rolled back."  If I try calling any method on the variable that has been assigned the CLOB, the method is undefined.  Thanks!!

Comment: This looks like the same issue I had with DB2, that I resolved by setting fullyMaterializeLobData="true"   But Derby doesn't seem to have a similar option.   You might have to use Java/JDBC to query the database. That way you can turn autoCommit off, and not commit the transaction until you have retrieved the CLOB data.  You can call your Java/JDBC method from your adapter instead of calling WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the great information.  I ended up getting this working using MySQL.  The Base64 encoded image was stored in a BLOB column.  To retrieve the data, my adapter SELECT statement looks like this:

```
selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select  *, convert(IMAGE USING utf8) as CONVERTEDIMAGE from report");
```

then in my client-side code, I loop through the resultset to grab the image which I  display via a Google Maps Marker in an infowindow

```
incidentRec.image = result.invocationResult.resultSet[i].CONVERTEDIMAGE;
 $marker.click(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': '<p> ' + incidentArray[this.id].description + '</br>' +     '<image + src="data:image/jpg;base64,'+  incidentArray[this.id].image + '"/>' + '</p>'}, this);
    });
```

When time permits, I can try the derby approach.  Thanks again!