# How to retrieve image from a CLOB column stored in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I want to retrieve a base64 image, stored as CLOB in oracle DB. to do this.I tried the approaches mentioned in [Retrieve base64 image stored as a CLOB from derby with Worklight adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891164/retrieve-base64-image-stored-as-a-clob-from-derby-with-worklight-adapter)

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/jsonstore_revisited_in_worklight_v6_part_1_the_adapter?lang=en

Here the driver class used is : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.
Query used:
select * from table_name;

Code in adapter :
var  clob = response.resultSet[0].CLOB_COL;
var bytes = clob.getSubString(1, clob.length());

Error :
Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot find function getSubString in object oracle.sql.CLOB.

Comment: Per the link from IBM site in your post, you need to be calling `getBytes` instead of `getSubString`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah tried the same. Get the error, "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot find function getBytes in object oracle.sql.CLOB"

Comment: I don't see how this is related worklight adapters. Run your query in the Oracle database UI. If it fails there as well, this has got nothing to do with worklight but with the query/driver.

Comment: When i run the query, i get response ,in oracle.sql.CLOB format. I want to retrieve the base64 image, in this CLOB

Answer (score 0):

TLDR : `oracle.sql.CLOB` is different than `java.sql.CLOB`. The sites you refer to talk about the second type but you are working with the first one.

---

As you can see from the [Oracle JDBC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/CLOB.html), the `oracle.sql.CLOB` type has no method `getSubString` nor `getBytes`.

However, `java.sql.CLOB` has the `getSubString` method you are looking for as you can see [in the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html). Even if they look quite similar, these are different types from different libraries. What you have to do is then convert your Oracle CLOB into a Java CLOB using the [`toJdbc`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/CLOB.html#toJdbc__) method from the Oracle api. The object returned will have the `getSubString` method you need.

So, technically, this should work :

```
var clob = response.resultSet[0].CLOB_COL.toJdbc(); // Oracle -> Java
var bytes = clob.getSubString(1, clob.length());
```

**EDIT for completeness** : you are also confused with the `getBytes` method which is a method that exists in `java.sql.BLOB` only. BLOB and CLOB and different types too. Be really careful with all the types and libraries. They all look the same but all have their own API. Especially when you take pieces of code from the web, you really need to know what types you are working with.

Comment: Error: TypeError: Cannot find function toJdbc in object oracle.sql.CLOB error is thrown

Comment: Then specify the versions of Oracle and the versions of JDBC your are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getString()` directly on the ResultSet object and then do the conversion from BASE64 to binary in Java.